# Reactive Extensions C# - How do I skip message while executing a (relatively) long-running subscription logic

Tags: c#, system.reactive, consumption

I am new to all of the Reactive programming concepts and I need to deal with the following situation -- I have a consumer logic that is relatively long-running, in a way that a couple of messages may be produced while a preceding message is still being processed.

I need to skip those messages and prevent calling the relevant consume logic for those. Here is an example (in C#)

```
IObservable<int> stream  = ...
stream.SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subsribe(ProcessMessage, cancellationToken);
```

Imagine that a message is pushed to the stream every 5 milliseconds: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

The `ProcessMessage` method may take about 10-15ms to complete, meaning when it received message `1`, it will still be working when `2` and `3` are being produced.

I need to skip calling `ProcessMessage` for `2` and `3` and catch up with `4` directly, or whatever the next unprocessed message will be.

Is there any built-in construct in Reactive extensions that allows me to handle this particular case?

Comment: Check out the [`ExhaustMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353907/how-can-i-implement-an-exhaustmap-handler-in-rx-net) operator. It may be exactly what you need.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, indeed this looks like what I am after. Thank you!

Comment: I will try to close this questions as a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353907/how-can-i-implement-an-exhaustmap-handler-in-rx-net

Comment: yep, that's a very elegant solution

Comment: AFAIK it should be possible to close your own question as duplicate single-handedly. I have closed a couple of my own questions this way. 

Comment: I thought so as well but I guess it is no longer the case. The only way I could close it is by pressing the `close question` link below, which just presented the close voting dialog :|. Maybe I need a few more rep to be able to directly close a question of mine, or maybe moderation flow changed. It was a long time ago when I closed my own question and I have almost no memory of the experience then

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's a rep thing. It may be an intermediate privilege between being able to vote open/close for any question, and being able to open/close any question single-handedly (a privilege that I see it abused quite often).