# Observable.FromAsync memory leaks [MelbourneDeveloper / Device.Net]

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, observable, hid

I am Using a slightly modified version of the HID Example from [melbournedeveloper/Device.NET library](https://melbournedeveloper.github.io/Device.Net/index.html) to poll an HID device every 100ms with a `TransferResult(byte[] data, uint bytesRead)` callback, using DotMemory the returned TransferResult seems to be leaking on every call

```
_hidObserver = Observable
          .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
          .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => _hidIDevice.ReadAsync()))
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
          .Subscribe(onNext: tuple =>
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("QUEUE | bytes transferred: " + tuple.BytesTransferred);
                  Console.WriteLine("QUEUE | bytes: " + tuple.Data);
                  return;
              },
              onCompleted: () => Console.WriteLine("HID Button Observer | Completed."),
              onError: exception => Console.WriteLine($"HID Button Observer | Error | {exception.Message}.")
          );
```

[image: Largest Retained Size]

[image: Snapshot Compare]

App normally starts with 70MB of memory,
leaving it running for 17 hours memory grew up to 1.8 GB

commenting out the observable part memory stays stable.

---

### Update 1:

Applying [@theodor-zoulias answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75638271/2919656) fixed the memory leak from continuous calls, however not all,
after extensive analysis, it tends out to be a problem with the HID Library itself leaking from the inside [MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net#219](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/issues/219)

related to these lines of codes:

```
private static extern bool HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref IntPtr pointerToPreparsedData); 
isSuccess = HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref pointerToPreParsedData);
```

should be without the ref keyword in regard of MS doc here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_freepreparseddata

```
private static extern bool HidD_FreePreparsedData(IntPtr pointerToPreparsedData); 
isSuccess = HidD_FreePreparsedData(pointerToPreParsedData);
```

Fixed by forking the Device.Net library and updating these 2 lines.

Comment: Have you looked at the .NET Memory counters in PerfMon (Performance Monitor). In a .NET app, memory naturally leaks in the short term; you really need to look over several garbage collection cycles

Comment: @Flydog57 I did leave this code running for 17 hours, memory grew to around 1.8GB, I have been doing long tests for the past two days.

Comment: Put that info in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> _hidObserver = Observable
>     .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
>     .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => _hidIDevice.ReadAsync()))
> ```

The `Observable.Interval` sequence produces a value every second, each value is projected to an asynchronous operation, and each operation is started immediately. There is no provision for avoiding overlapping. In case the `_hidIDevice.ReadAsync()` takes more than 1 second, a second `_hidIDevice.ReadAsync()` operation will start before the pervious has completed. Obviously this is not going to scale well. My guess is that the `_hidIDevice.ReadAsync()` has some internal serialization mechanism that queues incoming requests and executes them one at a time. There are also other possible scenarios, like `ThreadPool` starvation.

My suggestion is to prevent the overlapping from happening, by not starting a new operation in case the previous has not completed yet. You can find in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353907/how-can-i-implement-an-exhaustmap-handler-in-rx-net) a custom `ExhaustMap` operator that could be used like this:

```
_hidObserver = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    .ExhaustMap(_ => _hidIDevice.ReadAsync())
```

Comment: Does the observer keeps all the results in memory until subscriber is disposed or does it dispose old results on its own ?

Comment: Exhaust map fixed the leak, thanks

Comment: Could you look into update 1? any idea why G0 is stuck at first

Comment: @iceman2894 I am afraid I don't know the answer to that. My knowledge about the inner workings of the garbage collector is elementary.

Comment: @iceman2894 BTW another way of invoking an async method in periodic fashion, without overlapping, is the `PeriodicTimer` class. For an example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval "Run async method regularly with specified interval") question.